# How To Upload Image From Device To Server & How To Show On A Progress Bar How Much Data Has Been Uploaded?

Tags: android, image, upload, progress-bar

In my application , I want to do something like , when user clicks on a button it starts the device camera & when user capture an image , it should be uploaded to a server. Now , when uploading the image , i want to show uploading progress on a progress bar. So the question stands like this , how can i upload an image to server so that i can show uploading progress on a progress bar which is declared on a xml file ? Now , I need some idea / example / sample code on how can i do the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can i upload an image to server so that i can show uploading progress on a progress bar which is declared on a xml file ?

You can use [Android - AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Here is an example of uploading Image to server using AsyncTask [Android: Image upload activity](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/android-image-upload-activity/).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

xml file(imageupload.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

     <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Upload"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:text="Upload" />
<EditText android:id="@+id/Caption" android:layout_width="500px"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Write caption"

        android:singleLine="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Upload"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

ImageUpload.java:

```
package com.isummation.imageupload;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImageUpload extends Activity {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    private ImageView imgView;
    private Button upload;
    private EditText caption;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imageupload);

        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Upload);
        caption = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Caption);
        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (bitmap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ImageUpload.this, "Uploading",
                            "Please wait...", true);
                    new ImageUploadTask().execute();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.imageupload_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.ic_menu_gallery:
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        PICK_IMAGE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getString(R.string.exception_message),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String filePath = null;

                try {
                    // OI FILE Manager
                    String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                    // MEDIA GALLERY
                    String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                    if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                        filePath = selectedImagePath;
                    } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                        filePath = filemanagerstring;
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
                    }

                    if (filePath != null) {
                        decodeFile(filePath);
                    } else {
                        bitmap = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
        }
    }

    class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                        getString(R.string.WebServiceURL)
                                + "/cfc/iphonewebservice.cfc?method=uploadPhoto");

                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                entity.addPart("photoId", new StringBody(getIntent()
                        .getStringExtra("photoId")));
                entity.addPart("returnformat", new StringBody("json"));
                entity.addPart("uploaded", new ByteArrayBody(data,
                        "myImage.jpg"));
                entity.addPart("photoCaption", new StringBody(caption.getText()
                        .toString()));
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                        localContext);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

                String sResponse = reader.readLine();
                return sResponse;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getString(R.string.exception_message),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }

            // (null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
            try {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();

                if (sResponse != null) {
                    JSONObject JResponse = new JSONObject(sResponse);
                    int success = JResponse.getInt("SUCCESS");
                    String message = JResponse.getString("MESSAGE");
                    if (success == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Photo uploaded successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        caption.setText("");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getString(R.string.exception_message),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }

    public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp &lt; REQUIRED_SIZE &amp;&amp; height_tmp &lt; REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
}
```

imageupload_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/ic_menu_gallery" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
</menu>
```